# javascript, object logical and object, syntax error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wener/q3sZ9/);

Code example

```
eval("true && {a:1} && {b:2} && alert('this is ok');")

eval("{a:1} && {b:2} && alert('this should be ok~~');")
```

eval to skip syntax error.

What I missing ?

test:

29.0.1547.76 m win7

ie9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{a:1}` has two meanings in Javascript

- an object literal (as in `x = {a:1}`)
- a block of code with a label (as in `while(x) {a:1}`)

A concrete interpretation depends on the state of the parser when it encounters an opening `{`. In the "statement" state `{a:1}` will be a block, in an "expression" state - a literal. Since parsing always starts in the statement state, `{a:1} && x` will be read as `block && expression` which is a syntax error. On the contrary, in `x && {a:1}`, `&&` forces the parser to the "expression" state, and `{a:1}` will be a literal (no error).

To ensure `{a:1}` is always a literal, put an operator or a brace before it to make it an expression, e.g. `+{a:1}`, `!!{a:1}`, `({a:1})` etc.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the second string starts with a `{`, which is taken as the beginning of a block and not the beginning of an object literal. Try this:

```
eval("({a:1}) && {b:2} && alert('this should be ok~~');")
```

By adding the parentheses around the first object it doesn't get interpreted as the beginning of a block of code. (The second object, `{b:2}` is OK because it appears after the `&&` so at that point the interpreter is not expecting a block.)

http://jsfiddle.net/q3sZ9/1/

Note that this isn't because you are using `eval()`: if you put the content of your strings directly in your script you'd have the same issue.